# How to get data from rest api and show in angular js

Tags: json, angularjs

I am getting a JSON file from an URL which contains some movie data.

`http://movieapp-sitepointdemos.rhcloud.com/api/movies`

I have checked in Postman it works fine and showing data also. But when I try to show data on angular using `ng-repeat`  it does not show.

Please check why data is not displaying on it.

[Here is my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r7Cnso2MMQvqqaivbzu4?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats because in your `movies` object contains only `{"message":"Movie Added"}` object

here you can see example, ive [updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/BbDV6hpp1ivXxyXmdmA6?p=preview) , ng-repeat works as expected in another `batches` object , and also you can see what you get from server at the first line

Comment: but can you let me know how i can show all data not only message.

Comment: your json response only this data, you cant show another data because you receiving only {"message":"Movie Added"} after this request http://movieapp-sitepointdemos.rhcloud.com/api/movies

Comment: yes batches work fine but i need to display all movies data not only message how i can do it.
i have another link also
<http://www.listingsearch.com/service/test_function>

Comment: I have changed pluncker please see it http://plnkr.co/edit/BbDV6hpp1ivXxyXmdmA6?p=preview , thats what you need

Comment: so i am missing only get method??
if you have a time can you let me know is this object is also returning data or not?
http://www.listingsearch.com/service/test_function

Comment: Thank you Narek movies data works fine but 
second link not returning any data i dont know why ?
listingsearch.com/service/test_function 
is this link working at your side?

Comment: yes it returning {"id":"1","first_name":"Kelli","last_name":"Ward","office_phone":"8479980200","cell_phone":"8477325770","email":"kward@atproperties.com"}

Comment: Thank you did u check it in angular js i mean plunker please check it on plunker.its not opening on my compter

Comment: you cant see the object logged in screen ?